# Get 3 highest values from table

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to count the first 3 users who has the most attributed lines.

SQL Table:

```
ID | IdUser |  Type   |
-----------------------
0  |    1   |  like   |
1  |    1   |  like   |
2  |    4   | dislike |
3  |    5   | dislike |
4  |    1   |  like   |
5  |    4   |  like   |
6  |    5   |  like   |
8  |    4   |  like   |
9  |    4   |  like   |
10 |    3   |  like   |
11 |    5   |  like   |
12 |    9   |  like   |
```

Result should be:

```
idUser[1] with 3 times "like" and 0 "dislike" (3-0 = 3 points)
idUser[4] with 3 times "like" and 1 "dislike" (3-1 = 2 points)
idUser[5] with 2 times "like" and 1 "dislikes (2-1 = 1 point )
```

So what I'm trying to do is getting idUser 1 (3 points), then idUser4 (2 points) and finally idUser 5 (1 point) with their points.

I've tried different ways but none have worked.

Here I've tried to create a two-dimensional array with all data and then get the highest values but I couldn't do the second part.

Table 'users' has all users of the website
table 'points' has likes and dislikes recorded

```
$sqlUsers = "SELECT * FROM users";
$resultUsers = $conn->query($sqlUsers);

$recordsArray = array(); //create array

while($rowUsers = $resultUsers->fetch_assoc()) {

    $idUser = $rowUsers['id'];

    //COUNT LIKES OF THE USER
    $sqlLikes = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS numberLikes FROM points WHERE idCibledUser='$idUser' AND type='like'";
    $resultLikes = $conn->query($sqlLikes);
    $rowLikes = $resultLikes->fetch_assoc();

    //COUNT DISLIKES OF THE USER
    $sqlDislikes = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS numberDislikes FROM points WHERE idCibledUser='$idUser' AND type='dislike'";
    $resultDislikes = $conn->query($sqlDislikes);
    $rowDislikes = $resultDislikes->fetch_assoc();

    //GET POINTS BY SUBTRACTING DISLIKES FROM LIKES
    $points = $rowLikes['numberLikes'] - $rowDislikes['numberDislikes'];

    $recordsArray[] = array($idUser => $points);

}
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried and what the results were?

Comment: @PatrickQ I just edited my post

Comment: Have any of the answers solved the question? You've been given two (so far).

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: I don't think your question is about mysqli. I am going to change it to MySQL tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ultimately just need the total points without a breakdown of likes and dislikes (not totally clear from your question):

```
SELECT IdUser, SUM(IF(Type='like',1,-1)) AS points
FROM users
GROUP BY IdUser
ORDER BY points DESC
LIMIT 3
```

If you want the complete breakdown:

```
SELECT IdUser,
       SUM(IF(Type='like',1,-1)) AS points,
       SUM(IF(Type='like',1,0)) as likes,
       SUM(IF(Type='dislike',1,0)) as dislikes
FROM users
GROUP BY IdUser
ORDER BY points DESC
LIMIT 3
```

**Explanation**

Let's say I wanted to count the total number of rows where the `Type` column had the value `'like'`. I could execute the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM users WHERE Type = 'like'
```

But another, perhaps less direct way, is the following:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(Type = 'like', 1, 0)) AS cnt FROM users
```

In the above SQL the `Type` column in each row is being examined and if equal to `'like'`, then the value of 1 is assigned to the column otherwise 0. Then all these 1's and 0's are added up using the `SUM` function. By adding up all the 1's, you are in effect counting the number of rows that had `'like'` in the `Type` column. The second method allows you process the number of likes and dislikes with one pass:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(Type = 'like', 1, 0)) AS likes,
       SUM(IF(Type = 'dislike', 1, 0)) AS dislikes
       FROM users
```

But what if you wanted to get the above counts on a user by user basis? That is the purpose of the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT IdUser,
       SUM(IF(Type = 'like', 1, 0)) AS likes,
       SUM(IF(Type = 'dislike', 1, 0)) AS dislikes
       FROM users
       GROUP BY IdUser
```

The "score" or difference between the likes and dislikes can be computed if we assign the value of 1 to a column if it contains `'like'` and a value of -1 if it contains `'dislike'` (or isn't `'like'`) and then sum these values up:

```
SELECT IdUser,
       SUM(IF(Type = 'like', 1, -1)) AS points,
       SUM(IF(Type = 'like', 1, 0)) as likes,
       SUM(IF(Type = 'dislike', 1, 0)) as dislikes
FROM users
GROUP BY IdUser
```

Finally, if you want the three top scores, sort the returned rows in descending order (`ORDER BY points DESC`) and keep only the first 3 rows returned (`LIMIT 3`):

```
SELECT IdUser,
       SUM(IF(Type = 'like', 1, -1)) AS points,
       SUM(IF(Type = 'like', 1, 0)) as likes,
       SUM(IF(Type = 'dislike', 1, 0)) as dislikes
FROM users
GROUP BY IdUser
ORDER BY points DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: The second code is exactly what I needed! Thank you for the answer. But I wonder how it works, can you give me a few brief explanations?

Comment: I got it. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

See the solution below if you need to get likes/dislikes often, `points` table is being updated often and data relevance is important i.e. you don't want to cache the results.

Create another table like `user_points_summary` which will have 2 columns e.g. `IdUser` and `Points`. `IdUser` to be unique in this table, the `Points` recalculation (per user) must be triggered on adding new rows into the `points` table.

If you need likes/dislikes breakdown then this table will have 3 columns - `IdUser` (not unique anymore), `likes_count`, `dislikes_count`. And then the same - trigger this table update on inserting/updating/deleting rows in the `points` table.

If you go with the second option (with likes/dislikes breakdown) - here's an example of a create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_points_summary` (
  `IdUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `likes_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dislikes_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `idx_user_points_summary_IdUser` (`IdUser`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then you can add the following trigger to your `users` table which will add zero likes/dislikes on adding new users:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `users_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `user_points_summary` VALUE (NEW.`IdUser`, 0, 0);
END
```

Then add the following triggers to the `points` table to update `user_points_summary` likes/dislikes count:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `points_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `points` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.`Type` = 'like' THEN
        UPDATE `user_points_summary` SET `likes_count` = `likes_count` + 1 WHERE `IdUser` = NEW.`IdUser`;
    ELSEIF NEW.`Type` = 'dislike' THEN
        UPDATE `user_points_summary` SET `dislikes_count` = `dislikes_count` + 1 WHERE `IdUser` = NEW.`IdUser`;
    END IF;
END $$

CREATE TRIGGER `points_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `points` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.`Type` = 'dislike' AND OLD.`Type` = 'like' THEN
        UPDATE `user_points_summary`
            SET 
                `likes_count` = `likes_count` - 1,
                `dislikes_count` = `dislikes_count` + 1
        WHERE `IdUser` = `OLD`.`IdUser`;
    ELSEIF NEW.`Type` = 'like' AND OLD.`Type` = 'dislike' THEN
        UPDATE `user_points_summary`
            SET 
                `dislikes_count` = `dislikes_count` - 1,
                `likes_count` = `likes_count` + 1
        WHERE `IdUser` = OLD.`IdUser`;
    END IF;
END $$

CREATE TRIGGER `points_AFTER_DELETE` AFTER DELETE ON `points` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.`Type` = 'like' THEN
        UPDATE `user_points_summary`
            SET `likes_count` = `likes_count` - 1
        WHERE `IdUser` = `OLD`.`IdUser`;
    ELSEIF OLD.`Type` = 'dislike' THEN
        UPDATE `user_points_summary`
            SET `dislikes_count` = `dislikes_count` - 1
        WHERE `IdUser` = OLD.`IdUser`;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you can use the following query to get user points with likes and dislikes count:

```
SELECT *, `likes_count` - `dislikes_count` AS `points` 
FROM `user_points_summary`
ORDER BY `points` DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Yes, @Booboo answered what I was looking for, but your code is still interesting. I just wonder if the task that mysql will have to perform does not become too important especially when there are several hundred entries

Comment: @Azelkan Yes, you're right, with a few hundreds of entries, my solution would be an overkill